# How to replace name parameter in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and it has multiple rows and I need to replace the name attribute for every html element in each td.

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="finalizedCollections">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="[0].CustomerID" value="1"></td>
            <td>first100
                <input name="[0].CustomerName" value="first100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="[0].CollectionPayType">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="[0].CustomerID" value="1"></td>
            <td>second100
                <input name="[0].CustomerName" value="second100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="[0].CollectionPayType">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I have to replace value in `[ ]` for every input element present in each `tr`.

for example in first row `td`,input name attribute should be `[0].CustomerID` and in subsequent input elements `[1].CustomerId`.

The steps I am following is:

for each tr,check whether a input element is present in every `td` and if present replace the value in `[ ]` for name attribute,starting with 0 and for subsequent tr replace with +1 value

for ex, in first tr,all input values in all `td`s(if exists) should have `[0]`  and in next tr it should be `[1]` and so on.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not change it in the source (or what generates the source) instead?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan source gives this html and i need to modify the html for posting based on my business logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following example (inspect elements to check the name attribute)

**EXPLANATION**

- Iterate over each row and get the index.
- For each row, check if there is any input element and, if true, loop through them
- Split the `name` attribute by `.` , get the second part and store it to a variable (`'nm'`)
- Replace each name attribute with the row index followed by the `'nm'` variable

**EDIT (NOTE)**

If you want to change the `select` elements also, you could apply a common class to all of those elements you want to change and select this class in this line:

```
var inp = $(this).find('.common_class');
```

**CODE**

```js
$('table tr').each(function(index) {
   var inp = $(this).find('input');
   if (inp.length > 0) {
      inp.each(function() {
         var that = $(this);
         var nm = that.attr('name').split('.')[1];
         that.attr('name', '[' + index + '].' + nm);
      });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="[0].CustomerID" value="1"></td>
            <td>first100
                <input name="[0].CustomerName" value="first100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="[0].CollectionPayType">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="[0].CustomerID" value="1"></td>
            <td>second100
                <input name="[0].CustomerName" value="second100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="[0].CollectionPayType">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: awesome.it worked at the first run itself. Thanks much